Appache POI 5.2.2 XDDFDoughnutChartData getHoleSize() causes exception
I am playing with Apache POI trying to create a custom Doghnut Chart in PowerPoint.So i am testing getting the Doghnut holSize on existing Doghnut Chart in a ppt template from this code
else if (data instanceof XDDFDoughnutChartData){
        log.info("SUCCESS");

        XDDFDoughnutChartData pieData = (XDDFDoughnutChartData) data;


        Integer holeSize= pieData.getHoleSize();

and i am receiving
org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Could not locate compiled schema resource org/apache/poi/schemas/ooxml/system/ooxml/stholesizepercenta3d2type.xsb (org.apache.poi.schemas.ooxml.system.ooxml.stholesizepercenta3d2type) - code 0
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.XsbReader.<init>(XsbReader.java:63) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.resolveHandle(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:933) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaComponent$Ref.getComponent(SchemaComponent.java:113) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType$Ref.get(SchemaType.java:1072) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeImpl.computeFlatUnionModel(SchemaTypeImpl.java:1281) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeImpl.getUnionConstituentTypes(SchemaTypeImpl.java:1239) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlUnionImpl.set_text(XmlUnionImpl.java:88) ~[xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar:na]

and i am using POI version
        <apache.poi.version>5.2.2</apache.poi.version>

i am suspecting some version mismatch, but i have no idea which one ? Any ideas would be appreciated

Looking at the component map cited here for xmlbeans, you need the correct version of either ooxml-lite or
poi-ooxml-full.

If you ever see a message like this, try replacing the transitive dependency poi-ooxml-lite with poi-ooxml-full. poi-ooxml-lite covers the main use cases and is much smaller than poi-ooxml-full - but some use cases need poi-ooxml-full
